# Any material available on generalized power series?

Tags: analysis

I'm in my final year in my undergrad, and part of my thesis will involve generalized power series. Does anyone know of any good resources out there for learning about them? I struggled to find material on formal power series and have had no luck finding material on generalized power series.

Thanks!

Edit: I was asked to be a little more specific. I'm trying to learn more about formal power series that aren't indexed over the natural numbers (or at least, they don't have to be). They can be indexed by sets of real numbers. Specifically, a series is indexed by a support, which is, from my limited understanding, is an index that corresponds to non-zero coefficients of the series. The series is considered a generalized power series if the support is well-ordered. So a basic example of this could be a series indexed by real numbers n greater than or equal to 1, with indeterminate of the form $X^{(1-1/n)}$

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you mean by generalized power series? I assume you mean formal power series, so that one is not interested in convergence? I believe that most undergraduate algebra textbooks go into $R[[x]]$, the power series ring over a ring $R$, so this might be a good place to start.

Comment: Sorry if I was vague! I don't mean formal power series, but a generalization of formal power series. Convergence isn't necessarily something to keep in mind for what I'm trying to learn more about though.

Comment: Ah I see! Certainly you need not apologize for being vague, but I should apologize for being ignorant that such a thing exists! Unfortunately, I am unfamiliar with this topic and cannot be of assistance.

Comment: No need for apologies all around then. Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_series ?

Comment: Yes! That's exactly the kind of thing I'm looking at. I didn't know there was a more specific name. The resources on the page are a little sparse (and I don't know German), anyone know of sources on Hahn series then?

Comment: A good place to start might be *Transfinite Real Numbers* by André Gleyzal (1937)

Answer (score 0):

One of generalizations (more exactly, close relatives) are incidence algebras. If they are of interest for you, see [Incidence algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_algebra/%22Incidence_algebra%22) and a lot of papers about them.